# Error with Loading a lot of image from url Android Studio

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso

I have a **problem** that I really can't solve for a while and I need your help.

In my application, I get via a site the url of an indeterminate number of images (it can have 10 or 20 depending on the chapter).

So I make a for loop that creates the same number of ImageViews as the image taken from the site and **loads the images from their url** (with **Picasso**) that I just found.

The problem is that my application **suspends all my threads** and only half of the images are loaded and only the last ones.

The problem did not occur until I generated the APK to export the project to my phone.

I tried everything: change the library to load the image, create the imageView with xml and not javacode, avoid the loop and put all the lines manually but nothing worked.

My code here:

```
package fr.loawk.mangascantrad;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.AsyncQueryHandler;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class page_lecture extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_lecture);
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        int i = mIntent.getIntExtra("position", 0);
        String chapitres = mIntent.getStringExtra("chapter");
        try {
            chapitre(i, chapitres);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nous n'avons pas pu accéder aux images", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(page_lecture.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }


    public void chapitre(int i, String manwhaChap) throws IOException {
        class Chapitre extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                String manwhaTitle = DatabaseClient
                        .getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                        .getAppDatabase()
                        .manwhaDao()
                        .loadSingle(i);
                Log.d("F7UTI", "" + manwhaChap + manwhaTitle);
                String title = manwhaTitle.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-");
                String chapUrl = manwhaChap.toLowerCase().replace(".", "-");

                if(manwhaChap.contains(" ")){
                    chapUrl = manwhaChap.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-");
                }else if(manwhaChap.contains(" - FIN !")){
                    chapUrl = manwhaChap.toLowerCase().replace(" - FIN !", "-fin").replace(".","-");
                }
                if(title.contains("tales-of-demons-and-gods")){
                    title += "-scan-fr";
                }if(manwhaChap.contains("Vol")){
                    chapUrl = manwhaChap.toLowerCase().replace(".", "-").replace(" ", "-");
                }

                String url= "https://manga-scantrad.net/manga/"+title+"/"+chapUrl+"/";
                Document newChap = null;
                try {
                    newChap = (Document) Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Elements chaps = newChap.select("div.page-break.no-gaps");
                DatabaseClient2.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getAppDatabase2()
                        .chapterDao()
                        .nukeTable();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            LinearLayout myLayout = findViewById(R.id.Liner_layout);
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                            for(int j=0;j<=chaps.size()-1;j++) {
                                LinearLayout LinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Liner_layout);
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                                imageView.setCropToPadding(false);
                                LinearLayout.addView(imageView, layoutParams);

                                Picasso.get().load(chaps.get(j).select("img").first().absUrl("data-src")).noPlaceholder().tag("pas image").into(imageView);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                return;
            }
        }

        Chapitre st = new Chapitre();
        st.execute();


    }

}
```

My errors

```
2022-03-17 23:18:44.659 30187-30238/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/AbstractConscryptSocket;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
2022-03-17 23:18:45.028 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 5.057ms
2022-03-17 23:18:45.290 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 11.955ms
2022-03-17 23:18:45.406 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 7.369ms
2022-03-17 23:18:45.764 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad I/k.mangascantra: Waiting for a blocking GC Instrumentation
2022-03-17 23:18:45.973 30187-30207/fr.loawk.mangascantrad I/k.mangascantra: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 179282(9111KB) AllocSpace objects, 23(652KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 4217KB/8435KB, paused 11.954ms total 210.378ms
2022-03-17 23:18:45.973 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad I/k.mangascantra: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Instrumentation on Instrumentation for 208.988ms
2022-03-17 23:18:45.986 30187-30210/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
2022-03-17 23:18:46.080 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 5.858ms
2022-03-17 23:18:46.131 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad I/k.mangascantra: Waiting for a blocking GC Instrumentation
2022-03-17 23:18:46.249 30187-30207/fr.loawk.mangascantrad I/k.mangascantra: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 11827(654KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3799KB/7599KB, paused 573us total 119.059ms
2022-03-17 23:18:46.249 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad I/k.mangascantra: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Instrumentation on Instrumentation for 118.381ms
2022-03-17 23:18:46.341 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 5.245ms
2022-03-17 23:18:46.470 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 6.680ms
2022-03-17 23:18:46.524 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad I/k.mangascantra: Waiting for a blocking GC Instrumentation
2022-03-17 23:18:46.595 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad I/k.mangascantra: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Instrumentation on Instrumentation for 71.133ms
2022-03-17 23:18:48.021 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 9.859ms
2022-03-17 23:18:49.323 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 13.267ms
2022-03-17 23:18:49.668 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 7.308ms
2022-03-17 23:18:50.021 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 10.928ms
2022-03-17 23:18:50.047 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 16.346ms
2022-03-17 23:18:51.972 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 12.937ms
2022-03-17 23:18:53.926 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad I/k.mangascantra: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Instrumentation on None for 17.053ms
2022-03-17 23:18:54.097 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 19.992ms
2022-03-17 23:18:54.192 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 11.175ms
2022-03-17 23:18:54.219 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 9.839ms
2022-03-17 23:18:55.632 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 5.185ms
2022-03-17 23:18:55.653 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 9.342ms
2022-03-17 23:19:10.795 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 30.719ms
2022-03-17 23:19:11.778 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 9.566ms
2022-03-17 23:19:13.789 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 17.807ms
2022-03-17 23:19:21.808 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad I/k.mangascantra: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Instrumentation on None for 5.137ms
2022-03-17 23:20:11.802 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad I/k.mangascantra: Waiting for a blocking GC Instrumentation
2022-03-17 23:20:42.411 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 6.928ms
2022-03-17 23:23:39.282 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 5.406ms
2022-03-17 23:27:30.048 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 5.597ms
2022-03-17 23:27:30.093 30187-30226/fr.loawk.mangascantrad I/k.mangascantra: Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
2022-03-17 23:27:30.100 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad I/k.mangascantra: Waiting for a blocking GC Instrumentation
2022-03-17 23:27:30.758 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 8.190ms
2022-03-17 23:27:30.793 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 25.199ms
2022-03-17 23:27:32.909 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad W/k.mangascantra: Suspending all threads took: 17.207ms
2022-03-17 23:28:24.061 30187-30232/fr.loawk.mangascantrad I/k.mangascantra: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Instrumentation on None for 5.169ms
```

Comment: Dont use runOnUiThread() in doInBackground(). Execute that code in onPostExecute().

Comment: And do without that .get() for Picasso.

Comment: Further it comes to mind the question why you dont use a ListView or RecycleView with a list item containing an ImageView.

Comment: I finally put it in a listView, I didn't do it before since it's a tool I'm not very comfortable with and that I didn't consider as the solution to my problem, thanks a lot!